# WSO2 IS 5.9.0 TOML, How to enable SCIM2

Tags: wso2-api-manager, wso2-identity-server

Is anyone using WSO2 IS 5.9.0 with APIM 3.0.0? I am trying to enable SCIM2 and there is no TOML file configuration example in their support documentation.

Prior to IS 5.9.0, I updated the user-mgt.xml `<Property name="SCIMEnabled">true</Property>`. I tried this with 5.9.0 but no luck.

Appreciate any guidance. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Add it as below in deployment.toml file located in the /repository/conf/ folder.

```
[user_store]
scim_enabled=true
```

If there is already an [user_store] element in the deployment.toml file, add it under that element as **scim_enabled=true**

You can refer to the documentation also: **https://is.docs.wso2.com/en/5.9.0/setup/configuring-a-jdbc-user-store/#properties-used-in-jdbc-user-store-manager**

As per this doc, https://is.docs.wso2.com/en/5.9.0/setup/configuring-a-jdbc-user-store/#properties-used-in-jdbc-user-store-manager, you can use as below as well.

```
[user_store.properties]
SCIMEnabled=true
```